Why does loading markdown into Jupyter from file indent less than a markdown cell?
I'm making a large number of reports from jupyter notebooks. To save time from needing to tweak individual files by hand, I'd like to load repeated text from .md files. However, the loaded text has a different indentation compared to when running a markdown cell. I will need to fix it as the end result looks quite weird overall, and these are going on a public-facing site.
Attached is an image showing the indentation difference. I'm using python 3.12.4 and jupyter 7.0.8.

Can I fix this in an automated way?
Apologies if the answer is obvious, I haven't found anything similar online while searching for answers.

a markdown file *.md and a markdown cell in a jupyter notebook *.ipynb are two completely different objects.  So why treat them as the same ?

Does it still look different when you export it? How are you exporting it, for that matter? I don't use Jupyter much myself so sorry if there's an obvious way I'm not aware of.

@wjandrea I've been using nbconvert to convert to html thus far. The appearance is identical to above, where the markdown text imported from file is slightly less indented compared to rendered markdown cells.

@darren Point taken, though code cells and their print statements align with each other, as well as with the rendered Markdown cells. Just looking to see if there is a way to make the text from the .md uniform with all the rest.

As you found, the way you are doing this is less than ideal. You'd save more time and have more control if you start using nbformat to make these reports. You could then insert markdown text as markdown cells that way. You'd want to do this outside the report notebook though. You'd use an overarching control script or notebook to make the report ones. I use nbformat often to take templates of notebooks and make new notebooks. In a lot of cases if you put placeholders in the notebook file, you can just even use Python's string replace method. But nbformat could fix this case you have.

Lost of nbformat examples and info here.

Thanks @Wayne! I'll learn more about nbformat from your examples.
In this particular case I'm not sure it makes sense for me as it's semi-automated at best. While I'm re-using some amount of text I still need to add material / change code and structure depending on the processing results throughout the notebook. I might need to leave it as-is with inconsistent indenting, and can do an improvement (maybe nbformat) round later.

Yes, for the fix you could just make them all with your current approach and then process them all at the end in one go. Just put them in a directory and process any with .ipynb at the end that have that (display(Markdown as a cell.
